# Popup.html file for chrome extension doesn't seem to be rendering once the search bar icon is clicked. Anyone know why this might be?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

there! Thanks for your help in advance. I'm writing my first chrome plugin. Everything works perfectly except popup.html. My popup file includes no javascript--it's just a few links and some text. When I click on my icon in the search bar a little white box appears, but it is empty and no more than 10 by 10 pixels. I don't know what I'm missing.

At first, I thought it was a div sizing issue--maybe I just had to set the height and width of my `container` (largest) div and the window would resize accordingly. Nothing has changed :/.

My Manifest file

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "blah",
 "description": "blah",
 "version": "1.0.0",   
 "author": "MacKenzie Alessi",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "cool_image.png",
   "default_title": "Have a good day",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
  "icons":{
      "16": "cool_image.png",
      "32": "cool_image.png",
      "48": "cool_image.png",
      "128": "cool_image.png"
  },    

"chrome_url_overrides" : {
  "newtab": "newtab.html"
},
 "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Here is my popup.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>QueersHere</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'sha256-XNVQ5BKDALSf8uhDlSC492c/5DJ8JEMeFUJkofQAJD4=' ;">
```

then some google font links

```
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .container {
                top: 50px;
                left: 0;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                position: absolute;
                margin: 10px 20px 10px 35px;

            }
```

then some styling for buttons... probably not relevant

```
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="message">
                TEXT TEXT TEXT
            </div>
                <div class="button_cont">
                    LINKS LINKS LINK
        </div>


    </body>
```

Does anyone know why I just get a little teeny white box when I click on my icon in the search bar?

p.s. I've gotten no error messages.

Comment: Right-click the popup when it's shown, then click inspect, and inspect the DOM. I think the issue is that unlike normal pages in tabs/windows with fixed sizes the popups are auto-adjusted to the contents so your `position: absolute` on the container makes the body and html both shrink to 0x0 (plus borders around the popup).

Comment: So simple! That did it. Thanks a million.